# Fastboot devices returns nothing

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, root-access, fastboot

I have Asus Fonepad 7  dual sim (Build ver. 5.5.1).

I want to root my device.

`adb devices` recognizes my device properly.

Debugging
   mode is on.

Even device enters in fastboot mode by executing `adb reboot-bootloader` in terminal (I am using Ubuntu 14.04).

I have set
   up android rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules` .

I've
   found out my vendor id and product id using `lsusb` (when the device
   is in fastboot mode).  I've made corresponding entry in android rules
   file.  But even that didn't help.

I've tried `sudo fastboot devices`
   also.  Every time I get nothing but a blank line.

Somebody please help!!

Comment: Could you provide the `lsusb` line for the device and what you've added to the udev rules?

Comment: And please also check `lsusb` when booted into fastboot mode. I've seen several devices presenting different IDs depending whether they'd been booted to fastboot, recovery, or normal. Check you've got them all covered in your UDEV file.

Comment: When I am in `fastboot` mode `lsusb` gives me `Bus 002 Device 008: ID 8087:09ef Intel Corp.`  for my device. Corresponding udev entry is `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="8087", ATTRS{idProduct}=="09ef", MODE="0666",OWNER="aniket",GROUP="plugdev"` @Matthew Read @Izzy

Comment: Glad you got it rooted! I've moved my comment to an answer and reorganized. (Rather than editing the title, you can Accept an answer with the checkmark near the up and down arrows.)

Answer (score 1):

A bit of googling indicates that several people have had to build fastboot specifically to work with this device.  I found this one for Linux (last post) and have verified that it runs and isn't malicious: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/494961

Comment: That actually worked just fine! [This](http://www.mediafire.com/download/pbr4b2x2ig9b2m5/fastboot) link provided me "working version" of fastboot for my device. Now `fastboot devices` returns my device name correctly and all other fastboot commands work just fine.